# Port 80 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Fedora  I downloaded Tomcat 7 (apache-tomcat-7.0.34 , [url]http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat7-files/tomcat-7.0.34-preconfigured.zip[/url]) and then add it to eclipse(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Helios Release Build id: 20100617-1415). I want to start it from

[image]

but I get the following error:

Port 80 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

I checked which process is working on port 80

[CODE]
netstat -an|grep 80
ps -aux|grep tomcat
[/CODE]

and there is no process is working on port 80. There is no tomcat running.

also I checked with lsof

```
# lsof -p :80
lsof: illegal process ID: :80
lsof 4.86
latest revision: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/
latest FAQ: ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/FAQ
latest man page:   ftp://lsof.itap.purdue.edu/pub/tools/unix/lsof/lsof_man
usage: [-?abhKlnNoOPRtUvVX] [+|-c c] [+|-d s] [+D D] [+|-f[gG]] [+|-e s]
 [-F [f]] [-g [s]] [-i [i]] [+|-L [l]] [+m [m]] [+|-M] [-o [o]] [-p s]
[+|-r [t]] [-s [p:s]] [-S [t]] [-T [t]] [-u s] [+|-w] [-x [fl]] [--]     [names]
Use the ``-h'' option to get more help information.

# lsof -t -i:80
#
```

what are potential problem?
thanks

Comment: why not just running on 8080? Check if you have Apache2, it could be running on Port 80

Comment: What do you see when you open `http://127.0.0.1` in your web browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run eclipse on a Linux box, you most likely don't do that as `root`. In this case you can't open ports below 1024.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same situation.
I can give u another method to solve this problem.

double click Servers->server.xml,then u can see something like this.

[what in server.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPol4.png)

find out this line:

```
 <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8543"/>
```

change  `port=''80'`into another port,like `port=88`

Have a try~